# Android RecyclerView's OnTouchListener vs OnItemTouchListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to observe a single tap, double tap and long press on `RecyclerView`. I know that I can identify those gestures by means of `GestureDetector`, however, I am not sure where to place such a functionality.

It seems that I can do it with both `OnTouchListener` and `OnItemTouchListener`. Thus which one is the right place and why?

Furthermore, the former is quite straightforward but the latter is a bit mystery for me. Even though I have read the corresponding API documentation several times, I still do not get the difference between `onTouchEvent` and `onInterceptTouchEvent` methods.